# LaTeX Workshop Not compiling pdf properly (VSCode)

Tags: errors, mathabx, amsfonts

When I attempt to build my file in VSCode using LaTeX Workshop, the build icon runs and spins but then becomes a red X and the pdf does not update. This was working yesterday and all of a sudden it no longer works. I have confirmed that it is not an error in the document as it works in Overleaf.If I restart VSCode, the pdf is then compiled with the new updated stuff. Also, if I refresh all viewers, the pdf updates. Not sure why building or saving the document is not working to compile. I will attach the LaTeX compiler log:

```
Win CP console initial and current in/out Win: (437, 437), (1252, 1252)
Coding system for system and terminal: 'CP1252'
---
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77, version: 4.77.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
  c:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/Homework/2nd Year/Phys 206 - Homework/206 - Homework4.1.tex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
  pdflatex
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "c:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/Homework/2nd Year/Phys 206 - Homework/206 - Homework4.1.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/Homework/2nd Year/Phys 206 - Homework/206 - Homework4.1.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30> (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/eufrak.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cancel/cancel.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/mathabx/mathabx.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/mathabx/mathabx.dcl)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty

c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty:74: LaTeX Error: Command `\ulcorner' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.74 ...lcorner}{\mathopen} {AMSa}{"70}{AMSa}{"70}
                                                  

c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty:75: LaTeX Error: Command `\urcorner' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.75 ...rcorner}{\mathclose}{AMSa}{"71}{AMSa}{"71}
                                                  

c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty:76: LaTeX Error: Command `\llcorner' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.76 ...lcorner}{\mathopen} {AMSa}{"78}{AMSa}{"78}
                                                  

c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty:77: LaTeX Error: Command `\lrcorner' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77 ...rcorner}{\mathclose}{AMSa}{"79}{AMSa}{"79}
                                                  
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbraster.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfcol/pdfcol.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbhooks.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbhooks.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingsutf8.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingsutf8.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listingsutf8/listingsutf8.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbexternal.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbexternal.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbmagazine.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbvignette.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbvignette.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbposter.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbposter.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/esvect.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (483.69684pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (731.23582pt) is ignored.

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./206 - Homework4.1.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/uesvect.fd) [1{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./206 - Homework4.1.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `"206 - Homework4.1".out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathabx-type1/matha10.pfb>
Output written on "206 - Homework4.1.pdf" (1 page, 54702 bytes).SyncTeX written on "206 - Homework4.1.synctex.gz"

Transcript written on "206 - Homework4.1.log".
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,437)
Latexmk: Getting log file '206 - Homework4.1.log'
Latexmk: Examining '206 - Homework4.1.fls'
PWD line not in UTF-8
Latexmk: Examining '206 - Homework4.1.log'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to '206 - Homework4.1.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to '206 - Homework4.1.log' for details
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/Homework/2nd Year/Phys 206 - Homework" "c:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/Homework/2nd Year/Phys 206 - Homework/206 - Homework4.1"
```

```
Here is an example of the document:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\ptg}[2]{P(\text{#1 $|$ #2})}
\newcommand{\pt}[1]{P(\text{#1})}
\newcommand{\condpro}{\ensuremath{P(B|A)=\f{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}}}
\newcommand{\sepinta}{\int_{x_o}^{\xi(t)}}
\newcommand{\sepintb}{\int_{t_o}^t}
\newcommand{\gfx}[2]{$$$$\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}\end{center}$$$$}
\newcommand{\gradthree}{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k}}}
\newcommand{\gradtwo}{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}}}
\newcommand{\pfx}{\frac{\ensuremath{\partial f}{\partial x}}}
\newcommand{\pfy}{\frac{\ensuremath{\partial f}{\partial y}}}
\newcommand{\la}{\ensuremath{\lambda}}
\newcommand{\La}{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}
\newcommand{\D}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\ensuremath{\nabla}}
\newcommand{\eqz}[1]{\setcounter{equation}{0}\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\alt}[1]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\newcommand{\alz}[1]{\setcounter{equation}{0}\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\pa}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand{\pat}[3]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2\partial#3}}
\newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}}}
\newcommand{\K}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{K}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\C}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\li}[1]{\ensuremath{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\ensuremath{\widetilde{#1}}}
\newcommand{\s}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{sl}}}
\newcommand{\n}{$$$$}
\newcommand{\al}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
\newcommand{\bk}[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\newcommand{\inn}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}}
\newcommand{\cva}[2]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\cvb}[3]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\cvc}[4]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3\\#4\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\cvn}[3]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\\\vdots\\#3\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\mtwo}[4]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1 & #2\\#3 & #4\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\mthree}[9]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1 & #2 & #3\\#4 & #5 & #6\\#7 & #8 & #9\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\Itwo}{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\Ithree}{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\Ifour}{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\In}{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\nmat}[9]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix}#1 & #2 & \cdots & #3\\#4 & #5 & \cdots & #6\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\#7 & #8 & \cdots & #9\\\end{bmatrix}}}

\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=10mm,
right=10mm,
top=15mm,
bottom=15mm
}

\begin{document}
Dynamics
\n 
\n 
\textbf{1.(a)}



\end{document}
```

Comment: please show  complete document that generates that error (it can be empty apart from the preamble)

Comment: An example of one of the documents that fails to compile correctly has been added.

Answer (score 1):

A more reasonable example document is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\ulcorner' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.74 ...lcorner}{\mathopen} {AMSa}{"70}{AMSa}{"70}
                                                  
?
```

The `mathabx` fonts are an *alternative* to the AMS fonts so by design, the package defines commands of the same name but using the mathabx fonts and encodings.